# Launching Multiple .vbs and .bat scripts at same time

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm pretty new to .vbs and .bat, but is there a way to start multiple .vbs and .bat files at once with a few lines of script/code? The reason I'm asking this is because I'm trying to make a prank for a sibling/friend, and I want it to launch a .vbs file and .bat file for the prank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can just use `start`:

```
@echo off
start "" bat1.bat
start "" vbs1.vbs
```

And so on, this batch script will start them without waiting for each to complete.

Comment: The "" part is title for launched program (you can keep blank) and save it as .bat file